# Implementing bias-adjustion for step3 latent profile analysis in R

Tags: latent-variable, dependent-variable, finite-mixture-model, bias-correction

I am identifying a latent profile model with the Mclust package in R. After identifying an optimal number of cluster I would like to identify possible covariates and distal outcomes via logistic/linear regression.

The recommended approach is to use step3 model (1) as implemented in Mplus or LatentGold. These specialised softwares implement both maximum likelihood (ML) and The Bolck–Croon–Hagenaars (BCH) approach. However non was implemented in R. I have found only examplar implementation of ML by Daniel Tompsett and Bianca L De Stavol in a presentation found online (2), but the instructions are limited in the 3th step.

The ML is recommended for categorical variables, while BCH should be more suitable for continuous outcomes. Could someone provide me with guidance how to do so? Thanks

1. Bakk, Z., & Kuha, J. (2021). Relating latent class membership to external variables: An overview. The British journal of mathematical and statistical psychology, 74(2), 340–362. https://doi.org/10.1111/bmsp.12227
2. https://www.stata.com/meeting/uk22/slides/UK22_Tompsett.pdf